# How to disable screensaver in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, screensaver

How do you disable the screensaver/powersave function in Ubuntu 18.04?

In Ubuntu 16, you disabled the screensaver in two steps:

1. First, opening the screensaver gui and selecting "none". But this alone didn't stop the monitor from blanking.
2. The X server had its own powersave feature that would turn off monitor output when nothing on the screen changed. To disable that, you had to run `xset s off`.

In Xubuntu 18.04, the second part no longer works. Even though I've run `xset s off`, my monitor output still blanks if nothing changes after a few minutes. How do I fix that?

I'm running the XFCE desktop, with the xubuntu-desktop package, if that matters.

Comment: Which screensaver you are using? `light-locker` maybe? If you have `xscreensaver` installed, it may interfere display power management. IIRC you can configure `light-locker` via settings of `xfce4-power-manager`.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're running Xfce, you could try changing the settings of the Xfce Power Manager.

Find ***Power Manager*** in the Applications menu or run `xfce4-power-manager -c` from the terminal. Then you can change the settings in the ***Display*** tab.

If **Display Power Management** is turned **ON**, then the Power Manager should be in control instead of X11. You should then be able to prevent blank/sleep/power off by setting the appropriate sliders to **Never**.

Answer (score 1):

Try `xset s off -dpms`.

Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122825